# Why does a function that calls another with the same parameter name clobber its own parameter with that name?

Tags: powershell, recursion, parameters

Consider the following code:

```
function f2
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param( $e4da2f9 )
    process{}
}
function f1
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        $e4da2f9
    )
    process
    {
        $e4da2f9 

        $command = 'f2'

        $splat = @{
            e4da2f9 = 'value passed to f2'
        }

        # the following line clobbers this function's $e4da2f9...
        . $command @splat | Out-Null

        # ...but this line does not
        # f2 @splat | Out-Null

        $e4da2f9
    }
}

f1 'value passed to f1'
```

Running it, surprisingly yields the following:

```
value passed to f1
value passed to f2
```

If you comment out `. $command ...` and uncomment `f2 @splat ...` it yields the expected result:

```
value passed to f1
value passed to f1
```

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there some fundamental difference between calling a function plainly and calling it using `. $functionName`?
3. How do you call a function recursively using if you only have its name in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you dot-sourced the function rather than just running it (&).  You specifically said to run f2 in the scope of f1.

Replacing the offending line with this:

```
 & $command @splat | Out-Null
```

Makes it work like you want.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  And it's in black-and-white in [about_Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx).  I don't know how I missed that...

Comment: You don't see dot-sourced functions very often, so this is an unusual looking thing.